# Laravel Mongo enbedsMany not embedding documents

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel

Using the classic Posts and Comments example I am seeing that the embedsMany relation does not seem to be working where as hasMany works just fine. That is with hasMany I see the foreign key and all but with embedsMany I see no embedded document in Posts DB.

```
class Post extends Moloquent
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    /**
     * The name of the database connection to use.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $connection = 'mongodb';


    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->embedsMany('App\Comment');
    }

}


class Comment extends Moloquent
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    /**
     * The name of the database connection to use.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $connection = 'mongodb';


    /**
     * Get the case that owns the comment.
     */
    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
    }


}
```

My code to save:

```
 $comment = new Comment();
  $comment->text = 'This is a comment';
  $comment->save();
  $post = new Post();
  $post->text='some text blah blah';
  $post->comments()->save($comment);
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out. I shoudln't have saved the comment document.

```
 $comment = new Comment();
  $comment->text = 'This is a comment';
//  $comment->save();
  $post = new Post();
  $post->text='some text blah blah';
  $post->comments()->save($comment);
```